# Running a series of bash commands read from a txt file using python suprocess

Tags: python-3.x, bash, text, subprocess

I have created a python GUI that takes the input from the user and creates a text file. Each line on the text file contains a series of commands that are written in Bash. What I am having a hard time with is using the subprocess.run module to execute each of the lines in the txt file. My understanding is that by using subprocess.run I should be able to execute those commands but I cannot. I do think I am in the right track though.

Here is the portion of the code I am struggling with:

```
with open("C:/Users/rafae/Desktop/RafaProjects/test_commnds.txt") as bashtest:
    for line in bashtest:
        subprocess.run(line, shell=True)
```

This is the error I keep getting:
`'georun' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Thanks for the help, I've been stuck at this for about a week now and I honestly don't know what is it that I am doing wrong.

Since each line of the txt file in question is extremely long. I'm just going to post the first one.

```
(georun /PointClassMethod=SCP1 /SCP1PulseWidthLimit=5.5 /MTAOutputEnabled=no /MTAZone=AUTO /MTACalcMethod=AUTO /File:POFInput=E:/Projects/3186_QSI_PowderRiver_QL2/LiDAR/4319292a/05_INS-GPS_PROC/01_POS/sbet_4319292a.pof /PATH:GeoSysLib='C:\Program Files\Riegl_LMS\GeoSysManager 2' /File:GeoSysDB='C:\Program Files\Riegl_LMS\GeoSysManager\AirborneImaging_NAVD88.gsfx' /SourceCoordSystem=6342 /TargetCoordSystem=6342 /ScanCalibOffsetRoll=0.119580 /ScanCalibOffsetPitch=-0.106240 /ScanCalibOffsetYaw=0.529000 /PositionOffsetTime=0.00007 /NadirGateEpsilon=40 /File:SOCStoIMU='C:\Program Files\Riegl_LMS\SensorFiles\43_SOC2IMU.4x4' /File:IMUtoBODY='C:\Program Files\Riegl_LMS\SensorFiles\43_IMU2BODY.4x4' /File:POFOutput=431929201_1.pof /File:ACLInput=E:/Projects/3186_QSI_PowderRiver_QL2/LiDAR/4319292a/03_RIEGL_RAW/06_ATMOS/4319292a.acl /nogpu /LAS:GPSTimeStandard /LAS:CoordinateResolution=0.001 /LAS:IntensitySource=REFL /LAS:IntensityScaleMinimum=-25 /LAS:IntensityScaleMaximum=5 /File:DataInput=E:/Projects/3186_QSI_PowderRiver_QL2/LiDAR/4319292a/03_RIEGL_RAW/02_RXP/Channel_1/191021_165510_Channel_1.rxp /File:DataOutput=431929201_1 /Date:DataInput=2019-10-19 /OutputFileFormat=LASV1.4 /ProgressOutput=OFF &> 431929201_1.log; shutil.move('E:/Projects/3186_QSI_PowderRiver_QL2/LiDAR/4319292a/06_RIEGL_PROC/04_EXPORT/431929201_1.pof','E:/Projects/3186_QSI_PowderRiver_QL2/LiDAR/4319292a/06_RIEGL_PROC/04_EXPORT/pof') shutil.move('E:/Projects/3186_QSI_PowderRiver_QL2/LiDAR/4319292a/06_RIEGL_PROC/04_EXPORT/431929201_1.pof.log','E:/Projects/3186_QSI_PowderRiver_QL2/LiDAR/4319292a/06_RIEGL_PROC/04_EXPORT/logs') shutil.move('E:/Projects/3186_QSI_PowderRiver_QL2/LiDAR/4319292a/06_RIEGL_PROC/04_EXPORT/431929201_1.las.log','E:/Projects/3186_QSI_PowderRiver_QL2/LiDAR/4319292a/06_RIEGL_PROC/04_EXPORT/logs') las2las64 -set_extended_scanner_channel 1 -set_user_data 43 -set_point_source 01 -epsg 6342 -vertical_navd88 -set_ogc_wkt -i 431929201_1.las -o 431929201_1_temp.laz >>431929201_1.log 2>&1 && lasnoise64 -i 431929201_1_temp.laz -o 431929201_1.laz >>431929201_1.log 2>&1 && os.remove('E:/Projects/3186_QSI_PowderRiver_QL2/LiDAR/4319292a/06_RIEGL_PROC/04_EXPORT/431929201_1.las)os.remove('E:/Projects/3186_QSI_PowderRiver_QL2/LiDAR/4319292a/06_RIEGL_PROC/04_EXPORT/431929201_1.las)lasindex64 -append -i 431929201_1.laz >> 431929201_1.log 2>&1; shutil.move('E:/Projects/3186_QSI_PowderRiver_QL2/LiDAR/4319292a/06_RIEGL_PROC/04_EXPORT/431929201_1.log','E:/Projects/3186_QSI_PowderRiver_QL2/LiDAR/4319292a/06_RIEGL_PROC/04_EXPORT/logs'))
```

Comment: You are going to have a fundamental problem if you do that because each line will execute in a new, entirely separate process. So if your script changes directory, for example, and then on the next line, expects to be in the new directory, that will not be the case because the process that changed directory will have exited and a new process will be running in the default startup directory for the current line.

Comment: The system shell on Windows is `cmd.exe`, and that's what's running your command. Not bash.

Comment: that other guy! thanks for you input. I now think that's exactly why I keep getting the error that I get. I do have a terminal emulator for cygwin called mintty. I am sure you are familiar with it. do you know how could I call mintty instead of cmd?